# How to add SPM test targets in main app test plan?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, swift-package-manager

Is there a way to add a test target from local SPM to the main application .xctestplan?

I'm developing a modular app with SPM. I want to be able to run the tests and manage them in one place, test plans are the perfect place for that.

I added the SPM via

Project -> Package Dependencies -> + -> Add local

Here is a structure that I have

[image]

Then inside a test plan, I wan't to choose the MySPMLibraryTest test target, but it doesn't appear as a selectable option

[image]

SPM structure:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MySPMLibrary",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MySPMLibrary",
            targets: ["MySPMLibrary"]
        )
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MySPMLibrary"
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MySPMLibraryTests",
            dependencies: ["MySPMLibrary"]
        )
    ]
)
```

I'm using the latest Xcode 15.

Answer (score 0):

Found how to achieve that. Thanks to [this](https://developer.apple.com/forums/profile/alicerunsonfedora) developer. The next steps are from the [original post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/727587?answerId=757122022#757122022).

Step-by-step process:

- Create an Xcode workspace and iOS app project.
- Add the Swift packages and iOS app to that workspace.
- Create a test plan file (.xctestplan) by going to File > New > File... and select 'Test Plan'.
- In that test plan, add the Swift package tests (and any other tests) you'd like to execute.
- In the test section of the iOS app's scheme, add the existing test plan you created.
- Create an Xcode Cloud workflow as usual, targeting the test plan when adding the test action.

Comment: In the Xcode Cloud workflow do you set the project or workspace in the general settings? I keep getting errors when using the workspace complaining about the Package.resolved file is out of date when it is not.